# Inserting to an shell array in a loop

Tags: shell

I am trying to insert values in to an array in a loop as follows:

```
branches_to_delete=()
cat branches.txt | while read branch_name
do
   BRANCH_COUNT=$(git ls-remote | grep -w $branch_name | wc -l)
   if [ $BRANCH_COUNT -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "Branch does not exist"
     branches_to_delete+=($branch_name)
   elif [ $BRANCH_COUNT -eq 1 ]; then
     echo "Branch exists"
   else 
     echo "Not valid result"
   fi
done

echo "Loop finished"
echo ${branches_to_delete[@]}
```

But when I printout `branches_to_delete` it is actually empty.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you need an array anyway? Just do `git ls-remote | sed -n 's%.*refs/heads/%%p' | grep -xFf - branches.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the pipe from `cat branches.txt` into the read loop, you create a subshell that cannot access the parent shell's `branches_to_delete` array.

You can fix this by avoiding the pipe and saving a useless use of cat:

```
branches_to_delete=()
while read branch_name; do
  ...
done < branches.txt
```

(Make sure nothing in `...` reads from `read`'s stdin. You'll notice if something is missing).